# Macbook Air can't connect to internet after updating to Mojave

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, crash, internet

I recently updated my Mac to macOS Mojave, but it can no longer connect to the internet. It can connect to a Wi-Fi network (sometimes) but there is no internet connection. I have no Time Machine backups. When using my computer, it has been crashing quite often and it is really slow. I can't reinstall macOS Mojave because when I try restarting while holding Command+R, it is not connected to the internet and I get the error: The recovery server could not be contacted.

Comment: What is the OS version you're running? https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT209149#macos10144 10.14.4 should fix Wi-Fi connections. you can also remove the Wi-Fi interface and then re-add but I doubt if anything beyond that would be helpful except update(or a simple restart). Now the problem is, how do you get the update ?

Comment: I'd look for a wired ethernet solution.